# Create an app from JavaScript file and Item List

Tags: list, javascript, app

I have a javaScript file that pulls info from a custom SharePoint list. I would like to use this setup on some of my other sites as well. How can I make a sharepoint app so that I can click and drop the app without having to create a new list and copy the js file every time. I  don' want to publish the app just for my personal use on my websites.

Comment: Why not simply save the site as template?

Comment: Some sites are team sites others are publishing sites.

Comment: Can you be more clear about where this js file must be deployed in the site and from which page is referenced?

Comment: I reference the JS file in the master page. It should be allowed to be deployed on any of the sites pages.

Comment: Are these sites in the same site collection? Please be more clear about your target environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a Solution Package (Farm or Sandbox) in Visual Studio that uses Collaborative Application Markup Language (CAML) to create the List and a Module to provision the JavaScript file into a Library in the target site. This project would include a Feature that, when activated, would add the list and provision the JavaScript file.

This YouTube video will help you get started: [SharePoint 2010 for ASP.NET Developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=an1IkFzHpBk) . This video was made for SharePoint 2010 but the concepts also apply to SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint Online.